# Cat keeps escaping out it's cone

Tags: cats

My cat had an abscess removed from the base of it's tail. It left the cone on for 2 days but since then keeps escaping out of it soft cone. I have tightened it but she keeps escaping it. I am really getting worried she will chew the stitches and get more infected.

Comment: how old is your cat,is your cat on antibiotics,is your cat indoor only or does she go outside your house.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! There is a very similar question with good answers here. Please have a look into it (link above) and let us know, if or if not it helps your problem.